# How to darken an image completely?

Tags: javascript

I want to darken an image, but it isn't fully black in the end, because I can see the image some extent. I want to use vanilla JS only (no jQuery).
I have used a color array (colorArr), but I think there are much more elegant ways for darkening.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("img");
var colorArr = ["#fff","#ddd","#bbb","#999","#777","#555","#333","#000",];

var counter = 0;
var j=0;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    if(j < colorArr.length){
      element.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[j];
      j++;
    }  
  
    counter++;
    if(counter === 8) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 250);
```

```css
div.darken img {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
 
  <div class="darken">    
     <img id="img" 
            src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar2.png" />
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just replace the image with an all black one.

Comment: The image has a red tint at the bottom section which is visible on black background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do it using CSS and JavaScript.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("mask").classList.add("on");
};
```

```css
.dark-img {display: inline-block; position: relative;}
.dark-img .mask {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1; opacity: 0; background-color: #000; transition: opacity 2.5s linear;}
.dark-img .mask.on {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="dark-img">
  <div class="mask" id="mask"></div>
  <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar2.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

This technique allows me to use any colour and duration. Let's say orange for 1.5 seconds:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("mask").classList.add("on");
};
```

```css
.dark-img {display: inline-block; position: relative;}
.dark-img .mask {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1; opacity: 0; background-color: #f90; transition: opacity 1.5s linear;}
.dark-img .mask.on {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="dark-img">
  <div class="mask" id="mask"></div>
  <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar2.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **CSS only** solution!

```css
a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
            transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
            
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" class="darken">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" width="200">
</a>
```

Comment: What if the image has alpha like the one OP used in the question. No cheating!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Animations API, `Promise.all()` to animate the `background-color` of `<img>` `.parentElement` from `#fff` to `#000` and animate `<img>` element `opacity` to `0` in parallel.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("img");
element.parentElement.style.width = `${element.naturalWidth}px`;

const button = document.querySelector("button");
const colorArr = ["#fff", "#ddd", "#bbb", "#999", "#777", "#555", "#333", "#000"];

const settings = {
    easing: "linear",
    fill: "forwards",
    duration: 2500,
    iterations: 1
  };

button.onclick = () =>
  Promise.all([element.parentElement.animate(colorArr.map(color => ({
    backgroundColor: color
  })), settings)
  , element.animate([{opacity: 0}], 
  settings)]);
```

```css
div.darken img {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button>click</button>
  <div class="darken">
    <img id="img" src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar2.png" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @LGSon Which browsers have you tried to run `javascript` at stacksnippets?

Comment: @LGSon Which version of chrome? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility.

Comment: Try launching chrome with `--enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag. Note, all open instances of chrome should be closed, or also set `--user-data-dir` flag to a directory other than current configuration folder of running chrome instance; else new chrome instance will launch from same configuration folder as running instance - without flags

Comment: Well, another day I will try :) .... too much other stuff going on now so can't shut all down. And if this is what it takes to make your answer work, you might want to mention that in your answer :) .... and as you got my messages, I will also delete my previous comments now ... and soon this one too

Comment: @LGSon The compatibility charts are now in comments due to your comments, link to specification https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/#the-animatable-interface

Comment: Great...still, I copied your comment with the flags so I will be able to check later, if you decide to delete them

Comment: @LGSon See no need to delete comments. You may also be interested in `--javascript-harmony` flag; see http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/. Note, chrome is built using chromium FOSS source code https://fossbytes.com/difference-google-chrome-vs-chromium-browser/, https://www.chromium.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo element and keep the markup as is, add a CSS transition and then fire it with a hover or script, which ever suit best

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (){
    document.querySelector('.darken').classList.toggle('on');
  })
})
```

```css
div.darken img {
  background-color: white;
}

div.darken {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
div.darken::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
div.darken:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
div.darken.on::after {
  opacity: 1;
  background: lightgray;
}


@keyframes darken {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
 
  <button>Click here (or hover image) to toggle darken</button><br>
  
  <div class="darken">    
     <img id="img" 
            src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar2.png" />
  </div>

  
  </body>
</html>
```