# How to get consistently smooth HTML text scaling animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

## Brief Explanation

I need a way to scale text in an HTML document using JS, so I can easily use better easing functions and other functionality that CSS doesn't offer.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/aaronbeaudoin/pen/YQPjbL) showing 4 different method of doing the same scaling animation, so they can be compared side-by-side. The leftmost one runs smooth like I want, but I'm looking for a JS solution.

I'm using Chrome on Windows 10. For me, the text jitters during the JS animation (with libraries Velocity.js or Anime.js) if HA (hardware acceleration) isn't used. With HA enabled through adding a 3D transform (I added a `perspective` property on the parent), it looks blurry (but not jittery). In Edge, there is no blur, but with JS the text still jitters whether 3D transforms are enabled or not. On my iPhone, all methods (CSS or JS, HA or not) run perfectly smooth.

I'm looking for a JS solution that runs as smoothly as the CSS one. I don't know if this issue is caused by Windows, or something else, but there must be something I can do to fix it. I really like Velocity.js and especially Anime.js, and want to use them, but can have my text all jittery as it scales.

## More Explanation

It all started when I tried animating a `<p>` element on hover in the following way with CSS:

```
p {
    font-size: 2em;
    transition: all 4s;
}

p:hover {
    font-size: 6em;
}
```

Pretty simple. The problem was that as the text changed size, it jittered because apparent it gets changes in points. I don't like that. I want buttery smooth animations.

And so I embarked on a quest to find the best way to animate text size. I've decided that the answer seems to be to use some sort of scaling solution rather than changing the font size.

But now I've got another problem. I want to be able to use functionality that CSS either doesn't support or support very poorly, such as bouncy and elastic easing functions and animation chaining and queues. The best way there seems to be to do this is with JavaScript libraries. But now I have a problem. While CSS scaling with only 2D transforms gives the buttery smooth, pixel sharp scaling which I so desperately want, the JavaScript libraries (I tried Velocity.js and Anime.js) introduce the same jittery behavior I had when changing the font-size. And with either CSS or JS, if 3D transforms get enabled (causing hardware acceleration to be used by the browser) the text scaling becomes blurry.

And so I put together a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/aaronbeaudoin/pen/YQPjbL) to demonstrate visually what the problem is. Here's how they show up in 3 browsers:

**Chrome on Windows 10**

1. Perfect
2. Blurry
3. Jittery
4. Blurry

**Edge Browser on Windows 10**

1. Perfect
2. Perfect
3. Jittery
4. Jittery

On Chrome or Safari on my iPhone all are slightly blurry due the way HA handles the scaling, but the blur is hardly noticeable and so is not an issue.

## What I Want / Bottom Line

The buttery smooth animation of the pure CSS without HA via 3D transforms with the easing flexibility and animation separation from styling which a JavaScript library offers. There has GOT to be a workaround for this. If CSS can look smooth like it does for me in the first method, surely there is a library that uses some sort of similar smoothing technique to keep the text from getting jittery as it scales. Any help with this would be VERY MUCH appreciated.

Comment: _"but CSS doesn't support the easing functions I need"_ ? Not sure what you mean? What is Question? A library is not necessary to achieve animations, using either `css` or `javascript`.

Comment: Question: How can I make my JavaScript transform scale animation smooth like CSS? Right now it's all jittery.

Comment: What are the easing functions you need that aren't supported?

Comment: Easing functions with elasticity, bouncing, physics, etc... I know they're possible, but the libraries make them dead simple.

Comment: The simple Answer is to utilize `css`. You can alternatively use `javascript` [Web Animations](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/), see [How to darken an image completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43547220/), which ultimately applies `css`. See also `css` `cubic-bezier()` function. You will need to define your own custom curves.

Comment: CSS's `cubic-bezier()` is too limited in it's functionality.

Comment: Have you seen Animate.css - https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ ?

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin _"CSS's `cubic-bezier()` is too limited in it's functionality"_ What do you mean by "too limited"? Evidently not "too limited" to perform the effect described at Question at linked codepen. Again, you need to define your own curves on the graph. It appears you are asking to be referred to a library? The Question does not present an actual issue. In fact, no question is actually presented at OP.

Comment: See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#animation-timing-function, https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-timing-function

Comment: @guest271314 See http://easings.net The elastic and bounce ones are impossible with `cubic-bezier()`. The only way to emulate them would be to `@keyframe` the whole thing out. I'm too lazy for that. :)

Comment: _"The only way to emulate them would be to `@keyframe` the whole thing out. I'm too lazy for that. :)"_ Well, that is an issue. Your issue. Your inquiry is off-topic. Your do not have a programming issue, you have a "What I Want" "I'm too lazy for that. " issue; which only you can resolve.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I've seen Animate.css. Isn't it just a bunch of pre-made classes you can slap on to your elements? I want to design my own animations so I need more control.

Comment: _"I want to design my own animations so I need more control."_ Then do just that. That is the appropriate solution to your inquiry.

Comment: @guest271314 JavaScript libraries resulting in jittery text scaling is the problem I'm trying to solve. The bottom line here is that I'm not looking for a CSS solution. Perhaps my phrasing _"CSS doesn't support the easing functions I need"_ kind of led the topic down a rabbit whole. I'll rephrase that.

Comment: Asking for help with libraries is off-topic. A library is not necessary. Have you read the links previously posted?

Comment: I'd agree with @guest271314. It sounds like what you want is possible with CSS, but it will require SOME work. Probably about the same amount of work you'll do in trying to solve it with some JS. The Animate.css library should give you some ideas and inspiration on how to code it yourself as you can view the transforms used in the library to achieve certain effects.

Comment: The edit to original post still does not present a viable Question. _"There has GOT to be a workaround for this."_ `// do stuff`

Comment: @guest271314 Replicating specific easing functions or animations is not the problem I have. I can do that. But that is not the topic. The problem I have is that JavaScript animations involving the scaling of text are jittery. My apologies if I failed to convey this problem. If I wanted to go and simply reinvent the wheel  by rewriting library animations myself I wouldn't have posted this question.

Comment: _"The problem I have is that JavaScript animations involving the scaling of text are jittery."_ Then why have you determined that using `javascript` is a rational solution; where `css` renders expected effect described at OP? _"My apologies if I failed to convey this problem."_ Apologies are meaningless. Try to compose your own `css` `cubic-bezier()` functions, try several dozen `matrix()` variations, until you either  cannot or can achieve the expected result. Ask Question if you cannot. Currently the inquiry is not clear as to what expected answer is, if not the `css` example at  codepen

Comment: @guest271314 It's clear that you don't know how to help me make smooth JavaScript animations. Thanks for your input, however. I will keep it in mind. Unfortunately, I'm looking for solutions using JavaScript. I believe I made that very clear.

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin It is not a matter of knowing how to help. _"Unfortunately, I'm looking for solutions using JavaScript. I believe I made that very clear."_ No, the present inquiry is not clear. Why did you include `css`, `css-animations` tags at OP? Why do you, apparently, attempt to present the concept that `javascript` can animate `css` properties the same as `css` animating `css` properties? Use `requestAnimationFrame` for more precise animations using `javascript`. Or, the direct Answer is use `Web Animations` API.

Comment: @guest271314 _"I need a way to scale text in an HTML document using JS"_ and _"The leftmost one runs smooth like I want, but I'm looking for a JS solution."_ and _"I'm looking for a JS solution that runs as smoothly as the CSS one."_ and _"(What I Want) The buttery smooth animation of the pure CSS without HA via 3D transforms with the easing flexibility and animation separation from styling which a JavaScript library offers."_ I'm struggling to see how this was not clear. The CSS tags are there because the smooth rendering of CSS is what I'd like to emulate.

Comment: There is no "emulate" involved. `javascript` modifies `css` properties of an `Element` to render `css` effects. Do you need a direct and formal Answer to use Web Animations API?

Comment: @guest271314 So why doesn't it render the same? I'm a fairly new developer. I may be missing something, and I don't know what it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145925/discussion-between-aaron-beaudoin-and-guest271314).

Comment: Again, that is off-topic. Ask the authors and maintainers of the library about the issues with their libraries that you are referencing. You can use Web Animations as defined in the linked specification. What you are missing is that `javascript` requires use of `css` to adjust and render `css` effects at an `html` element.

Comment: @guest271314 I've submitted an issue to the library's GitHub page. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Using Web Animations https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzxeqJ

Comment: @guest271314 Interesting! This shows up perfectly, but it has spotty browser support. I will keep it in mind though.

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin _"Any help with this"_ , _"This shows up perfectly"_ What more are expecting within an Answer?

Comment: @guest271314 I said that because it actually didn't work at all on my iPhone.

Comment: Which leads back to why suggested using `css`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations#Browser_compatibility